# Relations in Parse.com

Tags: database, parse-platform

I have create an easy database in Parse.com. I don't know how to add objects to a relation because always I have to create a new one. This is my example.

I have a class called Person(name, surname, age,...) and other called Grade(grade(`number`), subject(`string`), personGrade(`Relation<Person>`))

So, when I add a new grade I can join that grade to a created Person, I have to create a new one, but I would like to use the same person for different grades. I mean using **Data browser**

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Yes, it is a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `Grade` to a `Person` this way (using JavaScript since you didn't specify):

```
var Person = Parse.Object.extend('Person'),
    Grade = Parse.Object.extend('Grade');

(new Parse.Query(Person)).get(personId, {success: function(person) {
    (new Parse.Query(Grade)).get(gradeId, {success: function(grade) {
        // 'grades' names the relation not the class
        // Parse infers the related class from the type of the grade object
        person.relation('grades').add(grade);
        person.save();
    }});
}});
```

Comment: Sorry, I would like to say using data browser

Comment: I'll leave this answer here for people doing searches.

Answer (score 1):

The data browser has an "add column" button in the class view.  You can choose a column type "Relation", in which case you get prompted for the target class in addition to the column name.

Once the relation is created, you can add items for individual rows in the data browser as well.